# Cordova remove: "android.permission.INTERNET" from config.xml

Tags: android, cordova

My app is a fully offline app with 0 plugins, but on the store, under permissions, it says "full network access."

Is it possible to remove "full network access" using the config.xml.
I have been reading online that in the AndroidManifest.xml this is added by default

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I am using voltbuilder which is compiles everything online.

This is all that exists in my config.xml:

```
<engine name="android" spec="11.0.0" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />   
<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
```